# Sitecore 7.2 Media Library images not working with underscore in the name

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I just upgraded a client's test installation of Sitecore to 7.2 (SP1) and now, any image that has an underscore in its name is throwing a 404 error when being referenced by a page. This was actually a series of upgrades from 6.4 so it's quite possible that a config setting somewhere got missed along the way, but I don't see anything standing out at me that would cause this problem.

If I change the image name to not have an underscore, it works fine, and it also works fine if I set "Media.UseItemPaths" to false, but they would prefer it if their image URL's had the file name displayed.

Can anyone help identify what may have gone wrong?

Comment: Check the `encodeNameReplacements` section in your config (via `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`) and make sure there is not a `replaceWith="_"` declaration.

Comment: @jammykam - That did it! Submit it as an answer so I can vote it up and accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to a change in Sitecore 7.1, any replacements specified in `encodeNameReplacements` are now also applied to media items as well as regular items in the content tree.

One option is to remove the `replaceWith="_"` declaration, but the likely reason this was added was to possibly replace spaces in your URLs so they do not display with `%20`. Removing this declaration will mean they return!

You can instead apply the fix specified in this Sitecore Knowledgebase article:  [Sitecore is unable to open media items when using encodeNameReplacements](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/998758)